# any option to make a area shrink when a drop down button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on jquery and javascript. I am using a drop down button which will be there on top right corner of the container.

So, is there any option to make a container shrink or move to left whenever the drop down button drops down when clicked. and the same vice-verse.

I too have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markipe/3DpfJ/45/) which has one the container which slides from left to right and reversal. but i am looking for a solution which  makes the container to shrinks or moves to left whenever the drop down button is clicked. here is the fiddle for it.

**CODE:**

```
      $('#sidebar').click(function(){
      $(this).animate({width:'100px'},{bottom : 100px}, 400);
      $('#steam').animate({bottom : 100px},{width:'500px'}, 400);

      });
        $('#steam').click(function(){
      $(this).animate({width:'100px'},{bottom : 100px}, 400);
      $('#sidebar').animate({width:'500px'},{bottom : 100px}, 400);
       });
```

Comment: Don't see any dropdown

Comment: Sorry here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/33rHZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below solution in js fiddle link.http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/50/

```
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/3DpfJ/50/
```

Comment: i have updated my fiddle. but there is small problem in it. so whenever i click the dropdown button the container shrinks. but it doe not regain to its original position when the drop down rolls up.   here is my updated fiddle with minor issues http://jsfiddle.net/PWduv/

Comment: @HkM - did u verified my jsfiddle link.  I did not understand your need.  From ur link, 1) In css you mentioned width as 49%. 2)Then, In onclick, you modified to 45%,  So, you did not write any code to regain its position back during "dropdown onchange".

Comment: Yes Sathish. thank you very much. i got the solution. here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YrhF3/1/.

Comment: @HkM - Glad to help you. It would be better, if you use onchange rather than onclick.  http://jsfiddle.net/PWduv/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/33rHZ/1/

This fiddle uses the `.change` event & I have commented out the check for `if expanded`, as I don't think you need it. But if you do, simply remove my comments and it should work fine.

In summary:

```
$(function()
  {
      $('#sidebar').change(function(){
          {
             $('#sidebar').animate({width:'69%'}, 400);
             $('#steam').animate({width:'29%'}, 400);
             $('#sidebar').animate({width:'29%'}, 400);
             $('#steam').animate({width:'69%'}, 400);
          }    
      });
  });
```

Very tidy.